# Free software appliance for graphite and grafana

Tags: gratis, virtual-machine

I know there is a commercial appliance made by NetApp but I am searching for a "readymade" virtual machine which contains:

- the operating system (which will presumably be Linux only)
- [graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- optionally InfluxDB
- [grafana](http://grafana.org/) >= 2.6
- all non-optional dependencies of the beforementioned software (Apache httpd, Python, ...)
- keeps itself current by automatically updating contained components (this is optional)

and is "free", that means can be downloaded and used commercially without having to pay fees for it. If optional support is available this would be nice but no requirement.

If no virtual machine image for VMWare or alike is available some easy to follow docker instructions of mid complexity would do too (I know that a vanilla operating system image can be modified to receive the components above but this is a kind of complexity I want to avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking of choosing a different different solution (http://prometheus.io) but nevertheless googled a bit the last days. I found no readymade ISO / VM for what I am searching but was able to create a plain Ubuntu VM and carried out the steps shown here: https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring/deploy-graphite-with-grafana-on-ubuntu-14-04 (which is too long so I am not copying it here)

After half an hour everything was set up.